# Android ALTER SQL databese - unable to open/read Desktop PC

Tags: android, sqlite, alter

After using `ALTER TABLE` to add column to table I was unable to open the db under Windows using many `SQLite` editors or browsers. Seems the problem is with the SQLite ver. that they support.

Is there tool that can open db that was modified with `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: You should tell more how did you run into this problem. I have never seen any problems reading sqlite databases from android device on windows or linux, using any sqlite tools - most importantly, `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

I found after 2hrs search the tool - SQLiteSpy (free - read the License)

Links:
http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index 
http://download.cnet.com/SQLiteSpy/3000-2065_4-75451503.html

Comment: You've ask and answered your own question at the same time?

Comment: Yes, it is called " Share knowledge " - option when you post a new Question you can find it at the Bottom - just put Checkmark and you are ready to go. 

3 times down? why? how many of you did ALTER table and then opened under windows with the tool that they use without any error?